# PayPal Express Checkout Shipping Address should not be editable

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I have already spent a lot of hours to find an answer for my problem but unfortunately i can't find a soloution.

I implement PayPal (Express Checkout) in our Shop-System. In our shop, the customer enters his shipping address. I don't want the customer to get the option to change his shipping address in PayPal. I only want the shipping address to be displayed which was entered before.

For example, here is an express checkout implementation like I want it:

Shipping Address only displayed:

[image]

How can i make this possible?

I use the `PayPalSDK` for `ASP.NET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SetExpressCheckout request you can add the ADDROVERRIDE parameter and set its value to 1.  Then make sure to include the shipping address parameters in your SEC request as well.

What this will do is simply display the address you pass over to PayPal without the ability for the user to change it.

> The value 1 indiciates that the PayPal pages should display the
>   shipping address set by you in the SetExpressCheckout request, not the
>   shipping address on file with PayPal.  This does not allow the
>   customer to edit the address here.  Must be 1 or 0

Here's a sample of an SEC request I just sent to the PayPal sandbox:

```
[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => *****
        [PWD] => *****
        [VERSION] => 97.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => *****
        [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
        [MAXAMT] => 200.00
        [RETURNURL] => http://paypal.angelleye.com/standard/samples/DoExpressCheckoutPayment.php
        [CANCELURL] => http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/cancel.php
        [REQCONFIRMSHIPPING] => 0
        [NOSHIPPING] => 1
        [ALLOWNOTE] => 1
        [ADDROVERRIDE] => 1
        [BRANDNAME] => Angell EYE
        [CUSTOMERSERVICENUMBER] => 555-555-5555
        [BUYEREMAILOPTIONENABLE] => 1
        [SURVEYENABLE] => 1
        [BUYERREGISTRATIONDATE] => 2012-07-14T00:00:00Z
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 100.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT] => 80.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT] => 15.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT] => 5.00
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => This is a test order.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => Tester Testerson
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 123 Test Ave.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => Kansas City
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => MO
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] => 64111
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRY] => US
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] => 816-555-5555
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTETEXT] => This is a test note before ever having left the web site.
        [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0] => Widget 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0] => Widget 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0] => 40.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0] => 123
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL0] => http://www.angelleye.com/products/123.php
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1] => Widget 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1] => Widget 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1] => 40.00
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER1] => 456
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1] => 1
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMURL1] => http://www.angelleye.com/products/456.php
        [L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY1] => Digital
    )
```

And here's what I see when I log in to PayPal as the buyer after this SEC call...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already tried this parameter. But in my situation, this parameter was ignored. Do you know if the parameter ADDROVERRIDE is dependent on antoher parameter or setting? Maybe it does not work in PayPal Sandbox?

Comment: Double check your request.  I just did this against the sandbox and it worked just fine.  I updated the answer accordingly.